# Убрать двойной клик по Dropdown в Navbar, Bootstrap 4.3

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, bootstrap

У меня на [сайте](https://kei-evenings.ml/team/) возникла проблема с кликами по ссылке Dropdown. Эта проблема возникла при подключении библиотеки отвечающую за вывод Tooltip-ов. До подключения этой библиотеки требовался один клик для развёртывания Dropdown. Как разрешить конфликт этих двух библиотек?

```
<!DCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- FONTAWESOME -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../fontawesome/css/all.css">
    <script src="../fontawesome/js/all.js"></script>

    <!-- jQuery 2.1.1 -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

    <!-- USER JS -->
    <script src="../js/js.js"></script>

    <!-- USER CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap');

* {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif!important;
}

.nav-item {
    --main-bg-color: none;
}

.navbar {
    position: fixed;
    top:0px;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 55px;
    z-index: 90;
    transition: .3s linear;
}

.nav-link {
    color: white!important;
    padding-top: .66em;
}


.toggl-icon {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1.5em;
    height: 1.5em;
    padding-top: .18em;
    color:#ED4949!important;

}
.navbar-toggler {
    background-color: white!important;
    transition: .2s linear;
}

.navbar-toggler:focus, .navbar-toggler:hover {
    outline: none!important;
    background-color: white!important;
}

/*Underline*/

.nav-link:after {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    height: 2px;
    width: 0%;
    background-color: #fff;
    transition: width .3s ease-in-out;
}

.nav-link:hover:after,
.nav-link:focus:after {
    width: 100%;
}
.dropdown-toggle:after {
    display: none;
}
/*Underline*/

.custom-bg {
    background: none;
}

.custom-bg:hover, :focus {
    background: #ED4949!important;
}

.nav-item:hover, :focus {
    background:var(--main-bg-color)!important;
}

.navbar-brand {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.scrolled {
    background: #ED4949!important;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px black;
}

.btn-custom {
    background:none;
    border:2px solid white;
    color: white;
    border-radius:30px;
    width: 9em;
    padding-top: .5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: .3s linear;
}

.btn-custom:hover , .btn-custom:focus {
    background: white!important;
    color:#ED4949;
}

</style>

    <title>KEI Evenings | Команда</title>
</head>
<body>
<header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark custom-bg">
          <a class="navbar-brand locked" href="../">KEI Evenings</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="toggl-icon"><i class="far fa-bars"></i></span>
          </button>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="../">Главная <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  Dropdown link <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                  <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="team/">Команда <sup class="b-test">β - тест</sup></a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-custom">Участвовать!</a>
            </form>
          </div>
        </nav>
    </header>

<!-- ...some content... -->
<!-- ...some content... -->
<!-- ...some content... -->


<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery , then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Tooltip Bootstrap -->
     <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script>
        $( function( )
        {
            $( "[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip( );
        } );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: странно, что стили bootstrap подключаете версии 4.3.1, а js bootstrap два раза: сначала 4.3.1, а потом отдельно- 4.1.3 (под <!-- Tooltip Bootstrap -->). зачем второе подключение, если в первом все уже есть?

Comment: @АлексейОбухов и вправду, не заметил)